# Запрет в поле type=text , type="number" нажатия клавиш "вверх" и "вниз"

Tags: jquery, css

Вопрос такой, как убрать запрет в поле type=text , type="number" нажатия клавиш "вверх" и "вниз".
Эти клавиши мне нужны для перехода на предыдущий/следующий блок.

```js
$("main").on("keydown",".element_count", function(e){
        var $next,$prev;
        switch (e.which){
            case 40://вниз
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).closest(".section_item").removeClass("active");
                $next=$(this).closest(".section_item").next();
                if ($next){
                    $next.find(".element_count").focus();
                    $next.addClass("active");
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            case 38://вверх
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).closest(".section_item").removeClass("active");
                $prev=$(this).closest(".section_item").prev();
                if ($prev){
                    $prev.find(".element_count").focus();
                    $prev.addClass("active");
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            default:
                console.log(e.which);
                break;
        }
        if (e.type == 'change') {
            change_input($(this));
        }
        return false;
    });
 function change_input(obj){

            var kratn = obj.attr("step"),
                koef,
                val = obj.val();
            if (val == "") {
                obj.val(kratn);
            } else {
                koef = Math.ceil(obj.val() / kratn);
                obj.val(koef * kratn);
            }
    };
        $('main').on('blur', ".element_count", function () {
            var kratn = $(this).attr("step"),
                koef,
                val = $(this).val();
            if (val == "") {
                $(this).val(kratn);
            } else {
                koef = Math.ceil($(this).val() / kratn);
                $(this).val(koef * kratn);
            }
        });

/*$("main").on("keypress", ".element_count", function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  var y = e.pageY;
  var $next, $prev;
  switch (e.which) {
    case 32: //пробел
      $(this).blur();
      $(this).closest(".section_item").removeClass("active");
      $next = $(this).closest(".section_item").next();
      if ($next) {
        $next.find(".element_count").focus();
        $next.addClass("active");
      }
      break;
    case 27:
      next = $(this).closest(".section_item").next();
      if ($next) {
        $next.find(".element_count").focus();
        $next.addClass("active");
      }
      break;
    case 40:
      $prev = $(this).closest(".section_item").next();
      if ($prev) {
        $prev.find(".element_count").focus();
        $prev.addClass("active");
      }
      break;
  }

  return false;
});*/
```

```css
.select_item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tablecatalog">
  <div class="select_item">
    <input type="number" class="element_count" min=1 step=2 value=1>
  </div>
  <div class="select_item">
    <input type="number" class="element_count" min=3 step=3 value=1>
  </div>
  <div class="select_item">
    <input type="number" class="element_count" min=3 step=3 value=1>
  </div>
</div>
```

как запретить прибавление/убавление значения поля клавишами вверх и вниз?

UPD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  if ((e.which == 38 || e.which == 40) && $(e.target).hasClass("element_count")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(".element_count").index(e.target);
    $(".element_count").eq(index + e.which - 40 + 1).focus();
  }
});
```

```css
.select_item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tablecatalog">
  <div class="select_item">
    <input type="number" class="element_count" min=1 step=2 value=1>
  </div>
  <div class="select_item">
    <input type="number" class="element_count" min=1 step=2 value=1>
  </div>
  <div class="select_item">
    <input type="number" class="element_count" min=1 step=2 value=1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: к сожалению, не работает при <input type="number" class="element_count" min=1 step=2 value=1>

Comment: @Rabin Что не работает в текущем коде ответа?

Comment: работает, просто я уже заработалась...
просто у меня не работает редактирование поля после включения события "keydown"

Comment: @Rabin Попробуйте задать новый вопрос с примером кода, демонстрирующим это поведение.